# Entity Framework saving children before parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Does Entity Framework support saving from bottom up though navigational properties like below?  I get a FK constraint error on ORDERID that suggests not.  The ORDERID is a FK to ORDERID (but this is not a PK)

```
someOrderItemEntity.OrderEntity = someOrderEntity;
someOrderItemEntity.ORDERID = someOrderEntity.ORDERID;
context.OrderItems.Add(someOrderItemEntity);
context.SaveChanges();

public partial class OrderEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ORDERID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItemEntity> OrderItemEntities{ get; set; }
}

public partial class OrderItemEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ORDERID { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderEntity OrderEntity{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does the parent `OrderEntity` to which you are trying to add items already exist, or are you trying to create it at the same time?

Comment: @BrianRogers - Trying to create it at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a FK constraint between the tables, then the parent `OrderEntity` will have to already exist in the database to add child items the way you are doing.

If you're trying to create both the order and the items at the same time, then I think you need to add the children to the `OrderItemEntities` collection on the parent `OrderEntity`.  Also make sure that both are in the same context when you call `SaveChanges`.